# Finding a new hamiltonian from a given canonical transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Let us suppose we have a given Hamiltonian

$$H = \frac{P_1^2}{4}+\frac{P_2^2}{2}+V(Q_2)$$

and $q_1 = Q_1 + Q_2/2$ with $q_2 = Q_1 - Q_2/2$. I need to find the new hamiltonian by using these canonical transformations.

My idea was to first find the generating functions. So I thought I can use $F_1(q, Q)$.

In order to obtain $F_1$, I guess I need to evaluate

$$dF_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{2}p_i dq_i - P_i dQ_i$$

and then Find $F_1$ and write the new Hamiltonian somehow but it also sounds wrong, since $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial t}=0$, $H'=H$? Any ideas how to approach to the problem?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes, $H'(q,p)=H(Q,P)$.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thats kind of confusing for me cause it kind of means that I can just replace $Q$ with $q$ and $P$ with $p$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the new $q(Q)$, it’s easier to use another generating function $F(p,Q)=pq(Q)$ (Legendre transform of your function) which gives:
$$
q = \frac{\partial F}{\partial p}(=q) \\
P = \frac{\partial F}{\partial Q}(=p \frac{\partial q}{\partial Q}) \\
$$
so all you have to is invert the jacobian according to the second equation.

Note that in this case, the Hamiltonian formalism is clearly overkill, as you could have found the result using Lagrangian formalism. The convenience of generating functions is more apparent when there is a more intricate mixing of the variables in $F$.

Hope this helps and tell me if you find a mistake.

Edit (detail of the calculation):

The second equation gives the system:
$$
P_1 = p_1\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial Q_1}+p_2\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial Q_1} \\
= p_1+p_2\\
P_2 = p_1/2-p_2/2
$$

which is a linear system that you can easily solve (the matrix that you are inverting is precisely the jacobian of the transformation $Q\to q$, which you could have figured out using Lagrangian formalism):

$$
p_1 = P_1/2+P_2 \\
p_2 = P_1/2-P_2
$$

thus completing your coordinate change.

Finally, plugging it back in your Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \frac{(p_1+p_2)^2}{4}+\frac{(p_1-p_2)^2}{8}+V(q_1-q_2)
$$
which worsened your expression, normally, you would go the other way round, I guess it was proposed for pedagogic purposes.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "invert the jacobian according to the second equation."... I am kind of new to this stuff, maybe you can show by equations..?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I did not see your edit...Can you just set $F_3=pq$, without any problem? Also when I looked the partial derivatives for $P_i$ and $q_i$, it seems that there should be "-" sign.

Comment: Also did you write, $P_i = \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial Q_i}$ ?

Comment: No problem. There is no extra sign from my definition, it rather corresponds to $F_2$ in the wikipedia article (just use as a sanity check the definition of $q$). No, as I’ve written above, $P_i=\partial_{Q_i}F$, later, I just calculate it (remember, the derivative is at fixed $p_i$ so I can take it out of the derivative).

Comment: Isn't it $F_3$ ? $F_3(p, Q)$, and $F_2(q, P)$ ..?

Comment: This is just a notation issue of what is capitalized or not. What matters is that my function is defined as $dF=qdp+PdQ$, which generates a canonical transformation.

Comment: I see...well I am still a bit confused but I also dont know much about the subject, so your suggestion seems right but Idk...

Comment: I strongly recommend Arnold’s Mathematical Methods for Classical Mechanics. Also, a more instructive (and useful) example would be that of the simple harmonic oscillator $H=p^2/2+q^2/2$. The relevant canonical transformation is $q,p\to J,\phi$ (action angle variables), with $q=\sqrt{2J} \cos \phi$, $p=\sqrt{2J} \sin \phi$ (you can also find it by solving the Hamilton-Jacobi equation).

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks